# How to get the full path of the currently installing debian file in control scripts?

Tags: debian, deb

I'd like to add a feature that display the md5sum of currently installing debian file in debian's control file: preinst, is there any way to obtain the full path of debian file ?

Answer (score 2):

It would be difficult.

Dpkg doesn't export the name of the currently installing file to maintainer scripts in any way, by environment variable or otherwise, and by the time maintainer scripts are run, it doesn't even have a handle to the original .deb file anymore, so even `/proc/$pid` inspection won't work. You could make something that would "sometimes" work by looking in apt's cache directory (config item `Dir::Cache`, typically `/var/cache/apt/`) for a file whose name is something like

```
${DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE}_packageversion_${DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_ARCH}.deb
```

..where you hardcode the current package version at build time, omitting any epoch field, cause dpkg won't provide you with that in the preinst either. That will work much of the time if you're installing using APT; if you use `dpkg -i` or something else, you're out of luck.

A better answer would probably be, why do you want to do that? There is probably a better way to solve whatever your problem is.

Comment: We have distributed our app to an alpha test user, and he failed to install our app and sent the failed screenshot to us, and we doubt that they download a corrupted deb file. If we print the MD5 sum of debian file in preinst script, that would be a great help to us.

Comment: Why not just have this user get the md5sum of the `.deb` he's trying to install directly?

Comment: A better solution, also, would be to distribute signed debs via APT; that way you and the user can be sure that the contents of the package are unaltered (and you get the security benefits as well).

Comment: We are developing a jailbroken app on iPhone platform. And the alpha users know little about the debian system, it is not easy to teach them to tell the deb file's MD5 sum in a simpler way on their iPhone.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Cydia already distributes signed packages. If so, you and the user can be sure you're getting the same thing when you install it.